# What's the voice command to stop voice-over midstream?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm using  iOS 17.3 with my iPhone 12.  If you enable “Accessibility -> Voice Content,” you can use a two-finger down swipe to get Siri to read what is onscreen (like your Gmail).   Sometimes it reads every thread in my email chain and I would like it to stop or at least skip to the next one.

How do you ask Siri to stop narrating?